# Getting invalid character in a Base-64 string

Tags: c#, base64, des

I have a 16byte hex key "**F81AFDEA26D680BF**" and also a **16byte encrypted text** in hex as "**3508D26A7064CF68**".
I need to use DES to decrypt the above text. i'm getting an error "invalid character in a Base-64 string". The code Im using is

```
static byte[] bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(KeyHexAscii("F81AFDEA26D680BF"));
public static string Decrypt(string cryptedString)
    {
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(cryptedString))
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("The string which needs to be decrypted can not be null.");
        }

        DESCryptoServiceProvider cryptoProvider = new DESCryptoServiceProvider();
        MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream(Convert.FromBase64String(cryptedString));
        CryptoStream cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(memoryStream,  cryptoProvider.CreateDecryptor(bytes, bytes), CryptoStreamMode.Read);
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(cryptoStream);

        return reader.ReadToEnd();
    }

  public static string Encrypt(string originalString)
    {
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(originalString))
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("The string which needs to be encrypted can not be null.");
        }

        DESCryptoServiceProvider cryptoProvider = new DESCryptoServiceProvider();
        MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
        CryptoStream cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(memoryStream, cryptoProvider.CreateEncryptor(bytes, bytes), CryptoStreamMode.Write);

        StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(cryptoStream);
        writer.Write(originalString);
        writer.Flush();
        cryptoStream.FlushFinalBlock();
        writer.Flush();

        return Convert.ToBase64String(memoryStream.GetBuffer(), 0, (int)memoryStream.Length);
    }
```

Comment: You are passing a hex-encoded (base 16) string to a method that accepts a base 64 string. What did you expect to happen?

Comment: I need to decrypt the particular encrypted 16hex using the key in 16 hex. suggest me with a code to do that.

Answer (score 1):

None of your data appears to be Base-64 encoded, so that's not the function you want to use.  It seems you already have a `KeyHexAscii` function, you'll want to use whatever function you've written that reverses that.

Ideally, you would write your crypto interfaces to operate on byte arrays.  It shouldn't be involved in encoding and decoding data.  You should handle reading data and converting it to bytes somewhere else.

Comment: `KeyHexAscii` turns hexadecimals to text instead of bytes. That is not a valid way of decoding hexadecimals. So whatever happens in `KeyHexAscii` is incorrect by definition.